# Does GPIO Linux framework support to change mode between GPIO and IRQ

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, interrupt, gpio

I checked the sysfs of GPIO, it only supports to configure the direction (in, out), active_level, edge.

I don't see it supports to change mode between GPIO and interrupt. Do any you know it ? Or any suggest.

Example:
Some GPIOs can supports either GPIO or IRQ. So I would like to change mode it under Linux via sysfs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The GPIO controller (and thus driver) will provide that support if any. In that case GPIO controller is registered as an interrupt controller.

There are a lot of examples, like [gpio-merrifield](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-merrifield.c) (in v6.4 the main part was moved to [gpio-tangier.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.4/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-tangier.c)) where you have:

### For the kernels before v5.5

```c
struct mrfld_gpio {
    struct gpio_chip    chip;
    ...
};
...
static struct irq_chip mrfld_irqchip = {
    .name           = "gpio-merrifield",
    .irq_ack        = mrfld_irq_ack,
    .irq_mask       = mrfld_irq_mask,
    .irq_unmask     = mrfld_irq_unmask,
    .irq_set_type   = mrfld_irq_set_type,
    .irq_set_wake   = mrfld_irq_set_wake,
};
...
    retval = gpiochip_irqchip_add(&priv->chip, &mrfld_irqchip, irq_base,
                      handle_bad_irq, IRQ_TYPE_NONE);
    if (retval) {
        dev_err(&pdev->dev, "could not connect irqchip to gpiochip\n");
        return retval;
    }
```

### For the kernels in the range v5.5..v5.19

For the above mentioned driver it was updated with the commit [4a5e0f9e7351](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/gpio/gpio-merrifield.c?id=4a5e0f9e73511595c68f907a15772e5d1ba4aac6) *("Pass irqchip when adding gpiochip")* to fulfill long standing TODO item in the GPIO subsystem, hence the code started looking as

```c
struct mrfld_gpio {
    struct gpio_chip    chip;
    ...
};
...
static struct irq_chip mrfld_irqchip = {
    .name           = "gpio-merrifield",
    .irq_ack        = mrfld_irq_ack,
    .irq_mask       = mrfld_irq_mask,
    .irq_unmask     = mrfld_irq_unmask,
    .irq_set_type   = mrfld_irq_set_type,
    .irq_set_wake   = mrfld_irq_set_wake,
};
...
    girq = &priv->chip.irq;
    girq->chip = &mrfld_irqchip;
    girq->init_hw = mrfld_irq_init_hw;
    girq->parent_handler = mrfld_irq_handler;
    girq->num_parents = 1;
    girq->parents = devm_kcalloc(&pdev->dev, girq->num_parents,
                     sizeof(*girq->parents), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!girq->parents)
        return -ENOMEM;
    girq->parents[0] = pci_irq_vector(pdev, 0);
    girq->first = irq_base;
    girq->default_type = IRQ_TYPE_NONE;
    girq->handler = handle_bad_irq;
```

### For the kernels starting from v5.19

The idea that IRQ subsystem maintainer proposed is to have IRQ chip definitions constant. For that some patches were provided and GPIO driver implementation has to follow as per [GPIO drivers providing IRQs](https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/gpio/driver.html#gpio-drivers-providing-irqs).

For the above mentioned driver it was updated with the commit [a80fed9fb643](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/gpio/gpio-merrifield.c?id=a80fed9fb643175832e2fb8481d38f5d92cbcd34) *("make irq_chip immutable")* and code started looking as

```c
struct mrfld_gpio {
    struct gpio_chip    chip;
    ...
};
...
static void mrfld_irq_mask(struct irq_data *d)
{
    ...
    gpiochip_disable_irq(&priv->chip, gpio);
}

static void mrfld_irq_unmask(struct irq_data *d)
{
    gpiochip_enable_irq(&priv->chip, gpio);
    ...
}
...
static const struct irq_chip mrfld_irqchip = {
    .name           = "gpio-merrifield",
    .irq_ack        = mrfld_irq_ack,
    .irq_mask       = mrfld_irq_mask,
    .irq_unmask     = mrfld_irq_unmask,
    .irq_set_type   = mrfld_irq_set_type,
    .irq_set_wake   = mrfld_irq_set_wake,
    .flags          = IRQCHIP_IMMUTABLE,
    GPIOCHIP_IRQ_RESOURCE_HELPERS,
};
...
    girq = &priv->chip.irq;
    gpio_irq_chip_set_chip(girq, &mrfld_irqchip);
    girq->init_hw = mrfld_irq_init_hw;
    girq->parent_handler = mrfld_irq_handler;
    girq->num_parents = 1;
    girq->parents = devm_kcalloc(&pdev->dev, girq->num_parents,
                     sizeof(*girq->parents), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!girq->parents)
        return -ENOMEM;
    girq->parents[0] = pci_irq_vector(pdev, 0);
    girq->first = irq_base;
    girq->default_type = IRQ_TYPE_NONE;
    girq->handler = handle_bad_irq;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is custom that GPIO drivers (GPIO chips) are also providing interrupts. So this combined driver is utilizing two sub-systems simultaneously: **gpio** and **irq**.
Usually GPIO controller will also serve as a secondary(child) interrupt controller:

> It is custom that GPIO drivers (GPIO chips) are also providing interrupts, most often cascaded off a parent interrupt controller

The most important two structures for GPIO drivers are  `struct gpio_irq_chip` inside `struct gpio_chip`. Fill in the struct `gpio_irq_chip` inside struct `gpio_chip` before adding the `gpio_chip` structure to kernel.
Inside `irq_chip` you define callbacks for acknowledge, mask and unmask of GPIO interrupts.

> The preferred way to set up the helpers is to fill in the struct gpio_irq_chip inside struct gpio_chip before adding the gpio_chip. If you do this, the additional irq_chip will be set up by gpiolib at the same time as setting up the rest of the GPIO functionality.

```
static const struct irq_chip xgpio_irq_chip = {
    .name = "gpio-xilinx",
    .irq_ack = xgpio_irq_ack,
    .irq_mask = xgpio_irq_mask,
    .irq_unmask = xgpio_irq_unmask,
    .irq_set_type = xgpio_set_irq_type,
    .flags = IRQCHIP_IMMUTABLE,
    GPIOCHIP_IRQ_RESOURCE_HELPERS,
};
.....
....
struct xgpio_instance *chip;
struct gpio_irq_chip *girq;
.....
girq = &chip->gc.irq;
gpio_irq_chip_set_chip(girq, &xgpio_irq_chip);
```

The following is a typical example of a chained cascaded interrupt handler using the `gpio_irq_chip`

```
/* Typical state container */
struct my_gpio {
    struct gpio_chip gc;
};

static void my_gpio_mask_irq(struct irq_data *d)
{
    struct gpio_chip *gc = irq_data_get_irq_chip_data(d);
    irq_hw_number_t hwirq = irqd_to_hwirq(d);

    /*
     * Perform any necessary action to mask the interrupt,
     * and then call into the core code to synchronise the
     * state.
     */

    gpiochip_disable_irq(gc, hwirq);
}

static void my_gpio_unmask_irq(struct irq_data *d)
{
    struct gpio_chip *gc = irq_data_get_irq_chip_data(d);
    irq_hw_number_t hwirq = irqd_to_hwirq(d);

    gpiochip_enable_irq(gc, hwirq);

    /*
     * Perform any necessary action to unmask the interrupt,
     * after having called into the core code to synchronise
     * the state.
     */
}

/*
 * Statically populate the irqchip. Note that it is made const
 * (further indicated by the IRQCHIP_IMMUTABLE flag), and that
 * the GPIOCHIP_IRQ_RESOURCE_HELPER macro adds some extra
 * callbacks to the structure.
 */
static const struct irq_chip my_gpio_irq_chip = {
    .name             = "my_gpio_irq",
    .irq_ack          = my_gpio_ack_irq,
    .irq_mask         = my_gpio_mask_irq,
    .irq_unmask       = my_gpio_unmask_irq,
    .irq_set_type     = my_gpio_set_irq_type,
    .flags            = IRQCHIP_IMMUTABLE,
    /* Provide the gpio resource callbacks */
    GPIOCHIP_IRQ_RESOURCE_HELPERS,
};

int irq; /* from platform etc */
struct my_gpio *g;
struct gpio_irq_chip *girq;

/* Get a pointer to the gpio_irq_chip */
girq = &g->gc.irq;
gpio_irq_chip_set_chip(girq, &my_gpio_irq_chip);
girq->parent_handler = ftgpio_gpio_irq_handler;
girq->num_parents = 1;
girq->parents = devm_kcalloc(dev, 1, sizeof(*girq->parents),
                             GFP_KERNEL);
if (!girq->parents)
    return -ENOMEM;
girq->default_type = IRQ_TYPE_NONE;
girq->handler = handle_bad_irq;
girq->parents[0] = irq;

return devm_gpiochip_add_data(dev, &g->gc, g);
```

When a GPIO is used as an IRQ signal, then gpiolib also needs to know if
the IRQ is enabled or disabled. In order to inform gpiolib about this,
the irqchip driver should call::

```
void gpiochip_disable_irq(struct gpio_chip *chip, unsigned int offset)
```

This allows drivers to drive the GPIO as an output while the IRQ is
disabled. When the IRQ is enabled again, a driver should call::

```
void gpiochip_enable_irq(struct gpio_chip *chip, unsigned int offset)
```

When implementing an irqchip inside a GPIO driver, these two functions should
typically be called in the `.irq_disable()` and `.irq_enable()` callbacks from the `irq_chip`. If not defined (NULL), these callbacks default to `.irq_mask()` and `.irq_unmask()` callbacks.

Like in this example from *gpio-cadence*:

```
static void cdns_gpio_irq_mask(struct irq_data *d)
{
    struct gpio_chip *chip = irq_data_get_irq_chip_data(d);
    struct cdns_gpio_chip *cgpio = gpiochip_get_data(chip);

    iowrite32(BIT(d->hwirq), cgpio->regs + CDNS_GPIO_IRQ_DIS);
    gpiochip_disable_irq(chip, irqd_to_hwirq(d));
}

static void cdns_gpio_irq_unmask(struct irq_data *d)
{
    struct gpio_chip *chip = irq_data_get_irq_chip_data(d);
    struct cdns_gpio_chip *cgpio = gpiochip_get_data(chip);

    gpiochip_enable_irq(chip, irqd_to_hwirq(d));
    iowrite32(BIT(d->hwirq), cgpio->regs + CDNS_GPIO_IRQ_EN);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I have updated mine. Note the main differences to yours: 1) refered the in-kernel documentation, 2) used the code that follows that documentation, 3) showed the history of the development, so it covers many kernel releases, 4) enabled syntax highlighting on SO.